# How to avoid reference count underflow in _NSCFURLProtocolBridge in custom NSURLProtocol in GC environment

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection, underflow

The basics are I have a custom `NSURLProtocol`.  In `startLoading`, `[self client]` is of type:

```
<_NSCFURLProtocolBridge> {NSURLProtocol, CFURLProtocol}
```

The problem is running this in a garbage-collected environment.  Because I'm writing a screensaver, I'm forced to make it garbage-collected.  However, the _NSCFURLProtocolBridge protocol seems to always throw:

> `malloc: reference count underflow for (memory_id_here), break on auto_refcount_underflow_error to debug`

An example dump to the debug console is:

> `ScreenSaverEngine[1678:6807] client is <_NSCFURLProtocolBridge 0x20025ab00> {NSURLProtocol 0x200258ec0, CFURLProtocol 0x20029c400}`
>     `ScreenSaverEngine(1678,0x102eda000) malloc: reference count underflow for 0x20025ab00, break on auto_refcount_underflow_error to debug.`

You can see that the underflow occurs for `<_NSCFURLProtocolBridge 0x20025ab00>`.

When I break on `auto_refcount_underflow_error`, it seems to stack-trace back up to `URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:` in:

```
id client = [self client];
...
[client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
```

This problem seems to have existed for a while, but there seems to be no answer at all online:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/May/msg01272.html
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2007/12/17/195056

The bug only shows itself in garbage-collected environments for these listed bugs as well.  Any thoughts on how I can work around this without causing memory issues?  I'm assuming this probably has something to do with the CF type underneath NSURLProtocol being released improperly?

Comment: A picture of the stack trace:
http://img.skitch.com/20090711-qbt4s4jq87jk4g68iaawe7h1hg.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last WWDC we confirmed this bug with a webkit engineer, he could see the bug right there in the code so hopefully they'll fix it. The workaround is to CFRetain the client in the initWithRequest method.

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request cachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse client:(id <NSURLProtocolClient>)client
{
    // work around for NSURLProtocol bug
    // note that this leaks!
    CFRetain(client);

    if (self = [super initWithRequest:request cachedResponse:cachedResponse client:client])
    {
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the implementation of _NSCFURLProtocolBridge.

Please use http://bugreport.apple.com/ and file a bug.  If you include the URL to this page, that would be appreciated (and if you update this page with the Radar #, that would be appreciated, too).  Ideally, if you can attach a binary of your screensaver, that would be very helpful;  no source needed.

Fortunately, it should not cause a crash.  Unfortunately, it probably causes a leak.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally indicates that an object was retained with `-retain`, but released with `CFRelease()`. If you believe that this could not be your object (and that's not a terrible belief), then you should open another Radar. But you should first look around and see if there's a CF object you're using `-retain` on when perhaps you should use `CFRetain()`.

The rest of this is shooting in the dark....

You may gain some insight by stepping up the stack and looking at the parameters that are  being passed to these C++ methods (or particularly `auto_zone_release`). Try this in gdb to try to see what's in the first parameter:

```
p *($esp)
```

And see if you can get any insight about the object being passed. Perhaps this will work if you're lucky:

```
po (id)(*($esp))
```

Comment: Rob - in a GC environment, aren't -retain calls NOOPs?  I do think this is a bug and I will open a Radar bug about it.  Thanks!

Comment: -retain is a NOOP in GC, but CFRetain() is not. So if you call -retain and then CFRelease(), you'll get unbalanced.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this issue by `CFRetain`-ing the client, and `CFRelease`-ing it again on the next call to `startLoading`

```
-(void)startLoading 
{
        if ( client ) CFRelease(client);
        client = [self client];
        CFRetain(client);
```

and, of course, in finalize

```
-(void)finalize
{
    if ( client ) CFRelease(client);
    [super finalize];
}
```

`client` is an instance variable of the `NSURLProtocol` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bug report I had filed a while back:

http://openradar.appspot.com/8087384

Probably worth filing as well, it's already been dup-ed, but it would be nice to get it fixed.

As Alex said, an Apple developer looked at the source code in front of me and located the issue easily with the example we had.

Comment: This bug was closed as a dupe of rdar://8070298, which seems to be fixed in Lion.

Answer (score 0):

the same error comes sometimes using NSURL in open dialog filter.
for me it was enough to set it to nil explicitly after I don't need it anymore.